# SQL adding one filter in outer query to apply to all subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating a query that contains multiple sub-queries that show number of incidents in different status/category/etc. A date filter will need to be applied to all sub-queries, in order to count number of incidents created within the date range.

Because the report will be moved to Business Objects, I cannot specify the dates multiple times in the sub-queries. Hence I joined the incident table (inc) in the sub-queries with another incident table (inc_filter) in the outer query, and hoping to apply one date filter to all sub queries.

But the result returned was incorrect, I got multiple rows that have the value either 0 or 1.

Could anyone please point me to the right direction?

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Incident inc
WHERE  inc.id = inc_filter.id
                 AND inc.status = 'Open')
            "Total # of Open Inc",
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Incident inc
WHERE  inc.id = inc_filter.id
                 AND inc.status = 'Closed')
            "Total # of Closed Inc"
--more sub-queries here...

FROM Incident inc_filter
AND inc_filter.CREATED > '10-Apr-2017'
AND inc_filter.CREATED < '13-Apr-2017'
```

Comment: Consider using a `CASE` expression, if all you are doing is `COUNT`. Maybe show the rest of your query to see the rest of your sub queries, could be simplified.

Comment: @Stephen please post this as answer, so we can vote for it!

Comment: A sidenote: You should not compare dates with strings. Especially not with ones that contain names, such as 'APR'. You are relying on database settings here and your query could easily fail when settings are different. Use ANSI date literals instead, e.g. `DATE '2017-04-10'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably simply looking for conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'Open' THEN 1 END) AS "Total # of Open Inc",
  COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'Closed' THEN 1 END) AS "Total # of Closed Inc"
-- more counts here...
FROM Incident 
WHERE created >= DATE '2017-04-10' AND created < DATE '2017-04-13';
```

Comment: Thank you. Definitely a faster solution too!

Answer (score 1):

First you should use `case` and you dont need use many subquery,
second if i understood your question you should use `sum()` like this

```
SELECT sum(case when inc_filter.status = 'Open' then 1 else 0 end) as open,
sum(case when inc_filter.status = 'Closed' then 1 else 0 end) as closed

FROM Incident inc_filter
AND inc_filter.CREATED > '10-Apr-2017'
AND inc_filter.CREATED < '13-Apr-2017'
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear you need one more select above this with using sum of your count. actually you are using group function but that is apply on row level. you need you sum all your subquery columns to see the required result for example your query will be

```
select sum("Total # of Open Inc") ,sum("Total # of Closed Inc")
from(
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Incident inc
WHERE  inc.id = inc_filter.id
                 AND inc.status = 'Open')
            "Total # of Open Inc",
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Incident inc
WHERE  inc.id = inc_filter.id
                 AND inc.status = 'Closed')
            "Total # of Closed Inc"
--more sub-queries here...

FROM Incident inc_filter
AND inc_filter.CREATED > '10-Apr-2017'
AND inc_filter.CREATED < '13-Apr-2017');
```

But it is better for you to use joins

Comment: I've formatted your answer for you. It's very easy by the way: simply highlight the code in the editor and click the {} button.